# Is there a minimal Debian ISO with a single CD image?

Tags: virtualbox, debian

I checked the Debian site, the images available are of five DVDs. I want a minimal edition that I can install in 1 or 2 GB VirtualBox drive.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't say whether your installation target has network access.  If so, you can use the netinst image and just install whatever else you require over the net.  If you don't have network access, you can download the first or first two 2CDs, which contain the most popular packages.

The [CD FAQ](http://www.debian.org/CD/faq/) will help you further.

Comment: I will be using on a single PC, however I use a USB wireless internet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the netinstall CD (128 MB) or the first CD of the set and add more software via the internet.